# Error Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server

I get the following error

> Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type varchar.

when trying to run the following code:

```
USE RESOURCES
DECLARE @SelectQuarter AS VARCHAR(6);
SET @SelectQuarter = (CAST(year(getdate()) AS char(4)) + 'Q' +
                     CAST(CEILING(CAST(month(getdate())-4 AS decimal(4,2)) / 3) AS char(1)));
```

I am trying to get the year and quarter for the **previous** quarter formatted as YYYY the letter Q and then the quarter number. e.g., today is January 3. 2024 so the value I want to get would be 2023Q4. If it were May 3, 2024 the value would be 2024Q1.

Any idea why this code is no longer working? Is it because it doesn't work for the first quarter of a new year? How can I modify my code to avoid this error?

Comment: FYI, whitespace and linebreaks are invaluable tools; please do get into the habit of using them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Month(GetDate())` is returning 1 in January, so the `Ceiling()` function is returning -1.  -1 is too long to cast to a char(1), which is resulting in an overflow.  If you change it to a char(2), you can get a clearer picture of what is happening, today (Jan 3 2024) your code will return `2024Q-1`.

I would instead use the `DateAdd()` function to update the date references to 1 quarter prior to today, and use the `DatePart()` function to get the quarter number directly without the `Ceiling()` or additional cast.

```sql
USE RESOURCES 

DECLARE @SelectQuarter AS VARCHAR(6); 

SET @SelectQuarter = (CAST(YEAR(DATEADD(q, -1, GETDATE())) AS char(4)) + 'Q' + CAST(DATEPART(q, DATEADD(q, -1, GETDATE())) AS char(1)));
```

This also makes sure the year is correct, otherwise the year in the string will be the current year, not the year of the previous quarter.

Comment: I did not check to see if hcaelxxam worked as Paul Pearce's answer mentioned the code allowing for previous year condition. The code Pal provided worked like a charm. Kudos to Paul and Yay from me!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `MONTH(GETDATE())` is returning 1 for January, then you are subtracting 4 resulting in -3.  -3 is two characters long, so it cannot be cast to `CHAR(1)`.

To fix, you should do this the other way, divide month by 4 and add 1.

```
CAST(FLOOR(CAST(MONTH(GETDATE()) AS DECIMAL(4,2)) / 4)+1 AS CHAR(1))
```